# Returning different types of unrelated data using generics without explicit knowledge of the return type beforehand

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.5

I would like to be able to query a class in my program for its available data. I would then like to request the class to return any of the data that is available. The main issue is that this data more than likely has nothing in common with any other types of data(i.e. do not share any common interfaces etc.) and since this code is going to be used by clients it would be nice if they did not need to explicitly know which type of object/interface is going to be returned when they request the data from the class which makes using generics hard.

My code currently looks something along the lines of this - https://ideone.com/s2fyGt but obviously is not as simple and the returned data types certainly are not as straight forward.

Is there any way I can change the request from looking like

```
var derivedOneParam = derivedOne.GetParam<ExtraDataOne>(supportedParam);
```

to something more along the lines of

```
var derivedOneParam = derivedOne.GetParam(supportedParam);
```

while still otherwise keeping the other behavior pretty much the same

Comment: suppose that works what will you do on the statements that follow with a variabele that has an unknown type?

Comment: Specifying the generic is good as it reports compile time error if any, rather than making it generic less and dealing with runtime error.

Comment: Both points are valid but as we are in control of the base code all variables should have a well defined type and we can deal with the runtime errors behind the scenes. We are trying to make it as easy as possible for the clients to use without having to know the type of every object(of which there are a fair few) beforehand.

Comment: @const_ref It seems to me that GetParam is the last point where you have any control over the code. At this point your clients *will* have to deal with the returned datatype in some way. I would have created an overload that returns `object` if the client wants to go for duck typing or when they just don't care, but I'd still keep the generic.

Answer (score 1):

If you really can't make those returned data implement a common interface, you can also access the object dynamically:

```
public override object GetParam(string supportedParam)
{
    ...
}

dynamic derivedOneParam = derivedOne.GetParam(supportedParam);
Console.WriteLine(derivedOneParam.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not possible without removing generic implementation of the method `GetParam`. Which I would never recommend to any person as commented in question.

**Note**: It would require the cast which in case of generic was not required because of compile time checks.

However you need to change a return type of the method from T to object like below:

```
public interface IAdditionalParams
{
    List<string> SupportedParams { get; }
    object GetParam(string supportedParam);
}
```

and then same in subsequent method implementation also.

One more alternative you can do. I am not sure weather it is acceptable or not as it would also required to pass generic parameter. 
**Make interface as generic.**

```
public interface IAdditionalParams<T>
{
    List<string> SupportedParams { get; }
    T GetParam<T>(string supportedParam);
}
```

Then you just need to specify generic while declaring the object.

```
IAdditionalParams<SomeType> parameters = GetSomeParamobj();
parameters.GetParam("string");
```

Making interface as generic would be great in your case if you have only few specific set of types (i.e. say 5 or 6) being returned by `GetParam`. In such case you can create [`Fecade`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) That would have predefined set of the instance of `IAdditionalParams` with different kind of Types.

Comment: They will still have to cast to the object so this doesnt really help. I guess we will just need to make sure our documentation is up to scratch and use the generic method

Comment: @const_ref Updated my question look at updated answer it might happen making interface as generic would help you.